# VS2015: The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ftp, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I have been using Visual Studio 2010 Pro for my vb.net desktop application development. I publish the apps via clickonce to a web server with ftp. My settings look like this:

Publishing folder location: ftp://www.webaddress.com/folder/

Installation folder : http://webaddress.com/folder/

This works perfect in VS2010.

I am now trying to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 community edition. When I try to publish my app, I get the error "The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed". I am getting this error on both computers I have installed VS2015 on.

Strangely enough, there isn't much info on this error. The only solution I've seen is to repair the installation. I did this but still a no go.. Another cause I read about is having Xamarin installed, but I have never had that installed.

Has anybody run into this and know what the fix is??

---

EDIT:

It appears to not actually have anything to do with installed components. After I posted this question, I realized the publish via FTP had worked earlier on a little sample Hello World project i made (brain fart). It was only once I loaded my existing project that this error started showing up.

I closed the solution, created another simple project, and still got the error. I closed visual studio, reopened the sample project, and ftp worked! I then opened my existing project and ftp worked there too?! So I don't know what the trigger is, and I haven't had it fail again yet, but maybe this info will help figure out what is causing the failure.

---

EDIT (3/30/2017)

Just an update - I am still having this issue. This issue happens on visual studio 2013, 2015, and 2017. I have tried reinstalling the c++ redistributable, still nothing. It seems others are having this issue with a web project but mine is a desktop app publishing with clickonce via FTP. It must be something to do with solution I am working on that was originally created in 2010, as the issue is not present in any other project.

Comment: I have this same issue now.  I'm using VS2015 Enterprise with update 1.  I swear this worked just fine yesterday.  Today, I get "The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed." message during publishing. I tried closing VS and re-opening; didn't help.

Comment: @SteveKennedy try some combination of closing VS, reopen and create a new sample project and see if FTP publish works. If so, then reopen existing project and see if that works. I haven't had the error appear since I did this...

Comment: Thanks. I eventually had to repair the installation - which seemed to work.  I wish I would've tried to create a new project, like you said.  Might have been easier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a total work around, but I've noticed I get this error every time I open my app (that originated in VS2010) and try to publish without first opening a sample app. I created a new project and published it to my FTP server. When I receive this error, I close Visual studio, reopen and the open the sample project, publish that app, then open my real app. The publish then works.

This works every time, and seems to be a bug in Visual studio, and probably has something to do with the fact that my app was originally built in 2010.

Maybe this will help somebody else with the same issue. It's a big pain so hopefully MS gets a fix in for this.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2017. What fixed it for me was to start the Visual Studio Installer and install the ".NET Core cross-platform development" workload.

Comment: worked for me too. this means there is some package dependency, wonder which one

Comment: THIS IS A BUG. ┓( ´∀` )┏ choose "asp.net web development" then remove others. there will be a prompt warning you relations between. ignore it. keep "desktop development" you have before and  only single "asp.net web development". it will solve the problem. but you can't modify installation again. installer will fix the installation remove broken "asp.net web development" and you will missing ftp component again.

Comment: +1, did exactly this and it worked perfect. Tried installing the C++ redistributable and still had the error. This solution is the one that worked for me. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2015 / Update 3. It was resolved after installing the 32-bit version of Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

See also https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/748

Comment: The download link above is broken, however if you search for `visual c++ redistributable  site:microsoft.com` on Google you'll get to the right place. Oh and, this works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2015. And Publish used to work fine so I went going crazy looking for and trying different solutions.   Then I read on another thread of doing a Setup-> Repair (submitted by Erikest).  I did a Setup->Repair and the publish process now works! I think it's also possible that the Repair not only did the trick on the FTP components but also replaced the C++ redistributable (often mentioned as a solution to this problem),

Answer (score 0):

I have been banging my head against this problem for many months, re-installed VS over and over and just did a clean install of Windows 10 in the hope it would work but to no avail. By chance I cleaned some old .accdb files from the App_Data folder that I no longer need since I converted to SQL Server database and FTP publishing now works.

So it seems VS does not like the .accdb files but was happy with .mdb files when publishing with FTP.

As soon as I put the file back in App_Data the problem returns. Hope this is some help.

Comment: This must be for a web project? Unfortunately mine is for a desktop app, I don't see an App_Data folder anywhere. Maybe it has something to do with old database files laying around though, because I do believe I have some of those.. I'll have to check. I'm still having this issue, thinking about downgrading to 2013 to see if that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here, I was using the Publish right click option on the project, which had been working fine. What fixed it for me was going back through the publish options and re-testing the connection. Publish seemed to work after that. Maybe it forgot a password or settings?

I also installed the x86 C++ Redistribution Package.

Hope this helps someone who is in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

After many successful website publishes with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, we experienced the "components for communicating with ftp servers are not installed" issue.  :(

First attempt at resolution was uninstalling VS Community 2015, then installing VS Community 2017.  Received the same error: "components for communicating with ftp servers are not installed"    when attempting to publish our business website.

With some work, we found that by uninstalling Microsoft Web Deploy and re-installing, this seemed to fix the problem.  We can now use Visual Studio > Publish function to our ftp without problems.

See this link for download of Microsoft Web Deploy components.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43717

Dont know what broke this VS IDE functionality, but hope this fix helps some.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error with Visual Studio 2019

I fixed it by using the Visual Studio Installer to install the Web Deploy (inc .netcore 2.1) under individual components

Answer (score 0):

I just did a simple "repair installation" in the installer. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 and had this problem for a while.
The problem went away after I updated about 10 NuGet updates that were over due.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I closed all the open windows I closed Visual Studio and then I opened again and published and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

VS 2015.  Same description as author in his/her edits (i.e., project specific, all my other projects publish fine).  The problem started when I changed to a new target server. It took a long time to figure this out, but what worked was simply to delete the publish profile and create a new one, clean/rebuild/build, exit VS, restart VS, problem solved.

(Must be rare problem because seven years have passed since this post.  The error message is still frequently posted with very few answers.)