# The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a WPF C# app (.Net Framework 4.5) which I regularly updated and **published to an FTP server using ClickOnce** (every few months). Now, when I want to publish it to the FTP server, it fails with the following error message: `The components for communicating with FTP servers are not installed.`

Searching the web and StackOverflow, I read that in some cases [Xamarin prevents](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30406/bug-after-installing-xamarin) publishing it, so I uninstalled Xamarin (as advised), but the problem persists. I also tried to publish locally and then manually copy the files to the FTP server, but then Windows Defender blocks the installation for the user. I also updated Visual Studio Enterprise to the latest version (Update 2).

It seems this issue has been there for quite a long time ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491499/vs2015-the-components-for-communicating-with-ftp-servers-are-not-installed), [two](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/338f95b6-19a3-48da-a975-662b4cb1e86c/the-components-for-communicating-with-ftp-servers-are-not-installed?forum=visualstudiogeneral), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755191/trying-to-deploy-clickonce-app-to-ftp-site-but-getting-frontpage-server-extensio)). Does anyone have an idea how to solve the issue, or what else I could try?

[image: Error-Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[kurtdv on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/338f95b6-19a3-48da-a975-662b4cb1e86c/the-components-for-communicating-with-ftp-servers-are-not-installed?forum=visualstudiogeneral&prof=required) suggested to install the 32-bit version of Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784, which solved my problem.